# Code review request for fizz buzz

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

Okay code reviewers, I need you to make my `FizzBuzz` code even better. Any suggestions for improvement, optimizations, etc.

```
public final class FizzBuzz {

    private FizzBuzz() {};

    /**
     * comparisons for a multiple of 3 = 2
     * comparisons for a multiple of 5 = 2
     * comparisons for a multiple of 15 = 2
     * 
     */
    public static void fizzBuzzBad() {
        // most common thought process
        for (int n = 1; n < 20; n++) {
            if (n % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("fizz");
            } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("buzz");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n" + n);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * comparisons for a multiple of 3 = 2
     * comparisons for a multiple of 5 = 2
     * comparisons for a multiple of 15 = 1 <--- here is the savings.
     * 
     * This saves the number of comparison for 15's.
     */
    public static void fizzBuzzBetter() {
        // most common thought process
        for (int n = 1; n < 20; n++) {
            if (n % 15 == 0) {
                System.out.print("fizzbuzz");
            } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("buzz");
            } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("fizz");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n" + n);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fizzBuzzBad();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        fizzBuzzBetter();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your methods should take the loop limit as a parameter.
2. You should separate computation from output. There are several options:

   - Pass in a `StreamWriter` you can write to
   - Pass in an interface with a `Write` method or similar.
   - Return a list of the results to completely remove the output concern.
   - Implement the `Enumeration<T>` interface to return the results which will completely remove the output concern from the class while not having to temporarily buffer them as with the list solution.
3. `fizzBuzzBad` is broken due to the use of `else if`.
4. You miss most of the line breaks in `fizzBuzzBetter`

Answer (score 4):

In both versions, your policy on printing newlines is inconsistent.  With `fizzBuzzBetter()`, all of your cases are mutually exclusive, so they should all be `System.out.println(...)` calls, and there is no need to prepend `"\n"`.

Your `fizzBuzzBad()` is wrong: it won't print `"fizzbuzz"` for multiples of 15.

Anything that can easily be parameterized ought to be.  Instead of hard-coding `20`, your functions should take a `max` parameter that is passed from main.